# C++: How to use thread_local to declare a pointer variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, thread-local-storage

I tried to declare thread_local pointer variable and then point to a new object in one thread.

```
thread_local static A* s_a = nullptr;
```

Seemed the memory of the new object was not released when the thread destroyed. I also tried to use unique_ptr, but still memory leak. I am using VS 2015.

Here is the code. Add a break point at `return 0`, check the memory of the process, you will see the memory increases a lot.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class A
{
public:
    A(const std::string& name) : name_(name) { std::cout << (name_ + "::A").c_str() << std::endl; }
    ~A() { std::cout << (name_ + "::~A").c_str() << std::endl; }

    const std::string& name(){ return name_; }
private:
    std::string name_;
};

thread_local static std::unique_ptr<A> s_a;
//thread_local static A* s_a = nullptr;

static void test(const std::string& name)
{
    //A a(name);
    if(!s_a)
        s_a.reset(new A(name));
        //s_a = new A(name);
}

int main()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        {
            std::thread t0(test, "t0");
            std::thread t1(test, "t1");
            t0.join();
            t1.join();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My question is how to use thread_local to declare a pointer variable in correct way?

Thanks.

Comment: I would like it is a singleton instance in a thread, what is the timing to delete it? why using unique_ptr still memory leak?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668729/memory-leak-in-gcc-4-8-1-when-using-thread-local. And a [gcc bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57914). Supposedly fixed in 4.8.2.

Comment: `static thread_local unique_ptr` should work. How do you know there is a leak?

Comment: I'm using VS 2015. Simply debug and stop at line "return 0;", see the memory of the process in task manger.

Comment: Release mode or debug mode?

Comment: Both release mode and debug mode.

Comment: Please show us the output from that code!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz，Did not you see the memory problem? Could you just copy and paste the code and have a try? I could not see the problem from the output, but the memory did increase a lot and not released.

Comment: @ldlchina How did you determine that the memory wasn't released to the process' memory manager? Checking the task manager doesn't do any good because that will include memory that has been released to the local memory manager since it still belongs to the process. I think you have no leak at all and I bet your output will demonstrate that the destructor was in fact called.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz，Thanks, you are right. The memory in task manager is not true. I used vld to demonstrate, No memory leaks detected.

Comment: You could tell from the output that the destructor was called. The destructor of the pointed to object can only happen if the pointer is destroyed, and the destruction of the pointer frees the thing it points to.

Comment: Right, the output is correct. Just the memory in the task manager is strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `thread_local static std::unique_ptr<A> s_a;` works. The memory in task manager is not true. I used vld to demonstrate the memory, No memory leaks detected.

Answer (score 1):

The standard's support for threading is *extremely basic*.

Boost's cross-platform support is of course superior:

```
// for thread_specific_ptr
#include <boost/thread/tss.hpp>


// define a deleter for As
void destroy_a(A* ptr) noexcept
{
    delete ptr;
}

// define the thread_specific pointer with a deleter
boost::thread_specific_ptr<A> s_a { &destroy_a };


static void test(const std::string& name)
{
    // create the object in a manner compatible with the deleter
    if(!s_a.get())
    {
        s_a.reset(new A(name));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this may work, I did not try. But for some reason, I cannot use boost.:(

Comment: So many people seem to be prevented from using boost in their work. To me this seems like walking with one leg. It's a shame.

Comment: Right. I agree boost is very useful.